# How does one construct the $n$th Brillouin Zone in a rectangular lattice geometrically?

Tags: solid-state-physics, fourier-transform, crystals, lattice-model

What are the general rules of constructing the Brillouin Zone in a rectangular lattice geometrically? While the construction of the 1st and 2nd Brillouin zone is rather simple, starting to construct the 3rd Brillouin zone is more difficult. What rules are here to consider? How do I reassure that the first Brillouin Zone contains 1 lattice point, the second 2 lattice points and so on?

Comment: Draw the Bragg planes. For each area defined between Bragg planes count how many planes you have to cross to reach it from the center. That is the number of the zone for that area. Done. (See, e.g., Ashcroft & Mermin chapter 9).

Comment: Look at these:https://www.doitpoms.ac.uk/tlplib/brillouin_zones/printall.php https://www.theory.physics.manchester.ac.uk/~godfrey/lecture/PHYS40352/NotesMAM.pdf  https://www.chem.tamu.edu/rgroup/hughbanks/courses/673/handouts/translation_groups3.pdf